# Display images in the same vertical position but right, center and left?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, boxes

I want to have three images of different horizontal size in the top of my document, but each with a different alignment:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
|top left image|           |top center image|            |top right image|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've used `\par` and `\raisebox` with `\hfill` to get the images at both sides, but adding a third in the top center seems to be not as straightforward as using another `\hfill`. Also the adjustbox package doesn't achieve the desired results as it modifies the vertical alignment, which is the same problem that `\hfil` suffers. How can I keep all images within vertical boundaries but each of them with different horizontal alignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\hrule

\bigskip

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}

\bigskip

\hrule

\bigskip

\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}\hfill
\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}


\bigskip

\hrule

\end{document}
```